# Ionic Braintree Plugin Error: Expected "/* Begin ", "/* End ", "\"", or [A-Za-z0-9_.] but "/" found

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

Each time I install the [Ionic Braintree plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/braintree/) and build for iOS, it throws this error right after the  `cordova build ios` terminal prompt

```
Expected "/* Begin ", "/* End ", "\"", or [A-Za-z0-9_.] but "/" found
```

I've tried removing the ios platform and then installing the plugin, then build for ios `ionic cordova build ios`. It breaks.

When I remove the platform and `ionic cordova build ios` it build the ios platform but as soon as I run `ionic cordova run ios` it throws the same error.

This error is only thrown for the ios platform, Android builds perfectly.

My cordova version in package.json is `"cordova": "^8.0.0"`

My braintree is `"@ionic-native/braintree": "^4.5.0"`

My ios is `"cordova-ios": "4.5.4"`

Can't seem to find a solution ‍♂️ online for this and thought someone here could help

**UPDATE**

Installing the `dpa99c` of the plugin seems to fix this

`ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-braintree`

Comment: Dealing with the same problem; your fix doesn't solve my problem. Did you do anything else?

Comment: There's also this version you can try [here](https://github.com/codinronan/cordova-plugin-braintree)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the question, and answer. If anyone's having issues, these are the steps that worked for me:

```
ionic cordova platform remove ios
ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-braintree
ionic cordova platform add ios
```

and then finally building. No more errors.

Comment: When I went to production bundle I ran into architecture errors. Don't bother with what's out there for Braintree for now, it's too buggy and under development. Go with the PayPal or Apple Pay solutions instead.

Comment: Even easier (and what I eventually went with) is Stripe. Soooo much easier!!